# Rotating a bunch of points on the sphere

Tags: 3d, rotations, spheres

If you had a bunch of points (on surface) around north pole ($n = (0,0,1)^T)$. How can we rotate all these points on the sphere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could use spherical coordinates...

Comment: We should apply a rotation matrix (that is, an orthogonal matrix with positive determinant) to their Cartesian coordinates we may precede any such rotation by any rotation around the north pole. But, how

Comment: I don't follow your last comment. Once you have a rotation matrix $R$, and the spherical coordinates rotation $S,$ matrix multiplication then does what you want. So what more is needed?

Comment: I think we can use  spherical coordinates